# getting value from uitextfield in uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have a lot of uitableviewcells with uitextfields inside. And i am catching the editing of the user with the delegate of the textField. That works fine as long as i don't use sections. Because i use the tag of the textField to save the indexPath.row of the cell.  The problem is that i have to use sections now and with the sections i would have to save the indexPath.row and .section somehow.

Here is some Code.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: textField.tag, inSection: 0)
  let cell : UITableViewCell? = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell?
  if data[(cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 10000) as! UILabel).text!] != textField.text {
    newData[fields[indexPath.row].ID] = textField.text
  }
  print((cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 10000) as! UILabel).text)
  print(textField.text)
}
```

Is there a better way to catch the edit of the textfields? Or how could i save both informations in the tag of the textfield?

greetings Adarkas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem like follows.

I have created a unique ID for my Datasource and i use that to determine with cell has been updated.

```
var row = 0
var section = 0

for var k = 0; k < fieldsWSections.count; k++ {
  for var kk = 0; kk < fieldsWSections[k].count; kk++ {
    if fieldsWSections[k][kk].ID == String(textField.tag) {
      section = k
      row = kk
    }
  }
}

if data[fieldsWSections[section][row].name] != textField.text {
  newData[fieldsWSections[section][row].ID] = textField.text
}
```

So i don't need to know the indexPath anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a different approach.
Instead of using tag, you could convert your `textfield` location and get the index path of its cell superview.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
  let origin: CGPoint = textField.frame.origin
  let point: CGPoint = textField.convertPoint(origin, toView: self.tableView)

  let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
  let cell : UITableViewCell? = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell?
  if data[(cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 10000) as! UILabel).text!] != textField.text {
    newData[fields[indexPath.row].ID] = textField.text
  }
  print((cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 10000) as! UILabel).text)
  print(textField.text)
}
```

Comment: i found a solution my self, but i am still gonna try your suggestion because i find it interesting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Adarkas2302: if you found a solution for this problem, you should really post an answer and accepted it yourself. It will help future reader when they have the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where on SO I saw this to give proper credit, but here's what I'm using in my app. You get the indexPath based on the textField's superview.

```
let textField = sender as! UITextField
let view = textField.superview!.superview!
let currentCell = view.superview as! UITableViewCell // Or substitute your custom cell class name
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(currentCell)
```

Comment: Ok i am getting an Error at `let currentCell = view.superview as! UITableViewCell`. I tried to do it exactly like that and i think i am getting the error because of my custom cells. But i have about 9 custom cells that are randomly distributed in the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Using tags is a bad idea for reusable code, but the other answers rely upon a precise structure of the hierarchy.

This helper function only expects that the UITextField is a child of the UITableViewCell and that the UITableViewCell is a child of the their UITableView, which should always be true when the UITextFieldDelegate is called. If either is not true, this returns nil.

```
    func indexPath(for view: UIView) -> IndexPath? {
      // find the cell
      var sv = view.superview
      while !(sv is UITableViewCell) {
        guard sv != nil else { return nil }
        sv = sv?.superview
      }
      let cell = sv as! UITableViewCell

      // find the owning tableView
      while !(sv is UITableView) {
        guard sv != nil else { return nil }
        sv = sv?.superview
      }
      let tableView = sv as! UITableView

      // locate and return the indexPath for the cell in this table
      return tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
}
```